# Angular Include Script From Node Modules Folder Using Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to include a `module` which requires `d3` and `nvd3` dependencies. In my `node_modules` folder I installed a package which contains `d3.min.js`.

So in my `index.html` I tried to include this script like this:

`<script src="./node_modules/ng2-nvd3/node_modules/d3/d3.min.js"></script>`

But I'm getting a `404` File not found error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I want to get this working: https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3

And in my `app.module.ts` I got this import statement: `import { NvD3Component } from 'ng2-nvd3';` and added it to the `@NgModule` decleration array.

What is the proper way to include this script? And how can I get it working?

Comment: What are you using to build your Angular 2 app (angular cli, webpack...)? I'm pretty sure the one you tried is not the best way to include such a script. I would rather import the module in eg. your core module.

Comment: Have you checked this module? https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3

Comment: @Yatinpatel I want to use exactly that module, but I don't know how to add the dependencies, I updated the question

Comment: @Matthias try to include script using absolute path.

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann - Once you install ng2-nvd3, it will add "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "d3": "^3.5.15",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.5"  this 5 modules. Why do you need to add d3.js in index file ?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann Please check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/T4i7Zh?p=preview

Comment: @Yatinpatel Ty, I will take a Look at it